# SFDX Jenkins Parse and install dependencies

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline to install package dependencies and my code looks like this:

```
def data = readJSON file:'sfdx-project.json'
for (item in data.packageDirectories.dependencies) {
    println "${item.package}"
    sh "${SFDX} force:package:install -p ${item.package}"
}
```

But whenever this runs in jenkins it fails with this error:

[2020-04-18T01:07:04.729Z] + node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run force:package:install -p '[PackageA@1.3.4-2,' PackageB@1.0.2-1, PackageC@1.0.0-1]'

[2020-04-18T01:07:05.300Z] ERROR running force:package:install:  Unexpected arguments: PackageA@1.0.2-1,, PackageB@1.0.0-1,, PackageC@1.0.0-1]

Here is how the Dependencies Map looks like:

```
        "dependencies": [
            {
                "package": "PackageA@1.3.4-2"
            },
            {
                "package": "PackageB@1.0.2-1"
            },
            {
                "package": "Packagec@1.0.0-1"
            }
        ]
```

To me it looks like that for some reason it is not properly iterating over the items in data.packageDirectories.dependencies.

Any ideas/Recommendations on how to solve this would be awesome. Fairly new to groovy so if I am doing something noobish point it out!

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging I came up with this:

```
def data = readJSON file:'sfdx-project.json'
def packages = data.packageDirectories.dependencies.flatten()                
packages.each { item -> 
println "$item.value"
   sh "${sfdx} force:package:install -p $item.value"
}
```

Taken from: 
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_maps